# Query html tag with XPath

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am writing the selenium test.

I have a label there "Assign Designer" and the select box followed right after the label.
Unfortunetely, select box has the dynamic id and I can not query it by id or any other it's attribute.

Can I build the XPath query that returns "First select tag after text 'Assign Designer'"?

PS. Selenium supports only XPath 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be something like:

```
//label[text() = 'Assign Designer']/following-sibling::select[1]
```

Note that:

- The // shorthand is quite inefficient, because it causes a document-wide scan. If you can be more specific about the label's position, I recommend doing so. If the document is small, however, this won't be a problem.
- Since I don't know much about Selenium, I used "label". If it is not a `<label>`, you should use the actual element name, of course. ;-)
- be sure to include a position predicate (`[1]`, in this case) whenever you use an axis like "`following-sibling`". It's easily forgotten and if it is, your expressions may produce unexpected results.

Comment: Does 'following-sibling' supported by XPath 1.0 specification?

Comment: What a strange question... Have you tried looking it up? http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#axes